# GA for iOS and custom dimensions

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics

We've setup Google Analytics in an iOS app which is sending the vendor identifier to distinguish between users on the reports. Here's what we've done:

In Google Analytics we've setup a Custom Dimension as follows:

Name: User identifier
Scope: User
Active: True

In the app we add the following in the AppDelegate:

```
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:uuidString]; // uuidString is the device identifier
```

In the logging window I can see that the value of `cd1` is the correct value yet our custom report shows no data for the custom dimension.

We are using Google Analytics 3.02.

Does anyone have any idea where we are going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sending the tracker?

This is an example from the [Custom Dimensions & Metrics for iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets#set-send)

```
// May return nil if a tracker has not yet been initialized with a property ID.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// Set the custom dimension value on the tracker using its index.
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]
       value:@"Premium user"]

[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Home screen"];

// Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
// Note that the value only needs to be sent once, so it is set on the Map,
// not the tracker.
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:@"premium"
                                                  forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was adding the value on the tracker but not adding it to the createAppView dictionary which appears to be where I went wrong as the data is now appearing.

Comment: Hi, Blexy. I saw you answered many questions related to GA. I have tried to follow your answers for Custom Dimensions but still got query about how can I have multiple custom dimensions which I have posted as an [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172712/google-analytics-for-ios-sending-custom-event-data-using-dictionaries-as-creat). I would appreciate if you can suggest me something.

Comment: How to reset the custom dimension/metric when not required? I tried by setting it to nil, however, I am seeing the value as "<null>" when that key is not used in other event.

Comment: @Noundla have you got any solution to this yet? If so, please share with us. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a required Dictionary Builder then set custom dimension on that builder, finally make a build from builder and call send method of tracker to send the build

```
    //MARK:- CUSTOM EXCEPTION TRACKING
    func doTrackCustomExceptionWithGA(message:String, customDimensionValue:String, isFatal:Bool = false) {

        guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance()?.defaultTracker else { return }

        guard let exceptionBuilder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createException(withDescription: message, withFatal: NSNumber(value: isFatal)) else { return }
        if !customDimensionValue.isEmpty {
            exceptionBuilder.set(customDimensionValue, forKey: GAIFields.customDimension(for: 15))
        }

        guard let build = exceptionBuilder.build() as? [AnyHashable : Any] else { return }
        tracker.send(build)

        // ADDING DUMMY EVENT TO TRACK PREVIOUS EVENT QUICKLY, AS GA EVENTS ARE TRACKED ON NEXT EVENT CALLS ONLY
        let event = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
        tracker.send(event?.build() as! [NSObject: Any])
    }
```

Hope this helps some one..