# Sending custom data to google analytics in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have integrated **google analytics** in my **iOS** project its working propers for events, i also want to sent my

> custom values (udid, userid, username..) with custom keys.
>
> Is it possible to do this?
>
> And if yes where can i find those value on *Google dashboard?*

i have tried

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set a custom dimension value just before the send call to which you
>    want the value applied.The defined scope of the custom dimension will
>    determine at processing time which additional hits may be associated
>    with that value.

That means a custom dimension is belong to a hit action(such as: sendView,sendAction)

Sample code for custom dimension:

```
// Get the tracker object.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker;

// Set the dimension value for index 1.
[tracker setCustom:1
         dimension:@"key1"];

// Dimension value is associated and sent with this hit.
[tracker sendView:screenName];
```

then you can see the output in Google analytics console, like [this](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/09/10/access-custom-dimensions-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=hpphmf%20dvtupn%20ejnfotjpo&ts=1384845402).

sample methods are already available in [analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets) page

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got your point but im still confused with if im supposed to send my value like **@"Suhas" for key @"username"** then _how m i supposed to do that?_ @Anbu

Comment: no customtrack only identify with index not in custom Names,

Comment: Ok, means i can set value to custom only!

Comment: i got it... you can see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172712/google-analytics-for-ios-sending-custom-event-data-using-dictionaries-as-creat/33035029#33035029