# Tracking button event in IOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

i want to track my button pressing event in Google Analytic's. I have completely integrated for Screens but have some issues in Button

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
```

Don't know how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
                                                  action:@"login_button_pressed"  // Event action (required)
                                                   label:@"Akshay"          // Event label
                                                   value:nil] build]];
```

for more reference [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events)

Comment: i also want to track the user who are using my app (user id ) how can i do that ???

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031882/sending-custom-data-to-google-analytics-in-ios/33032275#33032275